# Creating a custom filter for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filtering, prestashop

I'm trying to create a filter inside an ng-repeat. What I'm trying to achieve is a list -> more information on button click combination. I'm using the prestashop webservice for retrieving data. All the data is pulled from a `json` object.

So I did try some other solutions found on stack but sadly those didn't work for me. See the following example:

So my html exists of 2 blocks. One is a list of all orders, shortly summarized by id, date and the total paid amount. The other block would be the more information section. This section would show which products were ordered, at what date, etc.

So I've created the list and made the div (each list item) a clickable element by adding `ng-click`. (yes I did also try a `<button ng-click="function()">` but since it didn't made any difference between using the div or the button I've chosen for the div (layout).

So the `onclick` event grabs the order.id and adds it to a filter. This filter is then applied on the second "more information" block. This block should then filter this id and only grab that information. But that's where I've stranded since this part is still not working. So what I've tried so far is shown below:

**My HTML**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','cgNotify','pascalprecht.translate','ngCookies','ngSanitize']);


// Orders
myApp.controller('OrderController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('config/get/getOrders.php').then(function(response){
        $scope.orders = response.data.orders.order
    });
    $scope.currentOrder = {
        "id": 3
    };
    console.log($scope.currentOrder);
    $scope.showOrder = function(order) {
        var order_id = order.id;

        $scope.currentOrder = {
            "id": parseInt(order_id)
        };

        console.log($scope.currentOrder);
        return $scope.currentOrder;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- The list -->
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="OrderController">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="defaultinput col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-start">
            <svg class="align-self-center d-flex" height="20px" version="1.1" viewbox="7 5 20 20" width="20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <defs></defs>
            <path d="M27,23.5376923 L20.7969231,17.3046154 C21.7538462,16.0192308 22.3276923,14.4292308 22.3276923,12.7007692 C22.3276923,8.44769231 18.8969231,5 14.6638462,5 C10.4307692,5 7,8.44769231 7,12.7007692 C7,16.9538462 10.4307692,20.4015385 14.6638462,20.4015385 C16.4084615,20.4015385 18.0123077,19.8092308 19.3,18.8223077 L25.4476923,25 L27,23.5376923 L27,23.5376923 Z M8.35846154,12.7007692 C8.35846154,9.20692308 11.1869231,6.36461538 14.6638462,6.36461538 C18.1407692,6.36461538 20.9692308,9.20692308 20.9692308,12.7007692 C20.9692308,16.1946154 18.1407692,19.0369231 14.6638462,19.0369231 C11.1869231,19.0369231 8.35846154,16.1946154 8.35846154,12.7007692 L8.35846154,12.7007692 Z" fill="#8E8E93" fill-rule="evenodd" id="Search-Icon" stroke="none"></path></svg>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Zoeken' | translate }}" type="text">
        </form>
        <div class="row listrow" ng-repeat="order in orders">
            <div ng-click="showOrder(order)" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <p type="number" ng-bind="order.id" ng-value="order.id"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p ng-bind="order.invoice_date"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <p ng-bind="order.total_paid_real"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- The more information block -->

<div class="col-lg-11" ng-controller="OrderController">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="order in orders | filter: currentOrder" class="text-center margin-t-10">
            <div class="row listrow"></div>
            <h1>{{ 'Totaal' | translate }}</h1><h1 ng-bind="order.id"></h1>
            <h3>#010 - {{ 'Contant' | translate }} {{ 'Betaald' | translate }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row listrow margin-t-20 no-border">
            <div class="col-6">
                Blauw shirt - Maat: L
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                2x
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 text-right">
                € 200,00
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row listrow no-border">
            <div class="col-6">
                Blauw shirt - Maat: L
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                2x
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 text-right">
                € 200,00
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-t-30 justify-content-end">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        {{ 'Subtotaal' | translate }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                        € 400,00
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row listrow">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        21% {{ 'BTW' | translate }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                        € 84,00
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5 padding-r-5">
                        {{ 'Totaal' | translate }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 align-self-center no-padding">
                        <h6>(2 items)</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 padding-l-0 text-right">
                        € 484,00
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-t-100 d-flex justify-content-around">
        <button ng-click="" type="button" class="smallbutton defaultbutton">{{ 'Print bon' | translate }}</button>
        <a href="#/refund">
        <button type="button" class="smallbutton defaultbutton">{{ 'Retour' | translate }}</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The JSON example**

```
{"orders":{"order":[{"id":"1","id_address_delivery":"4","id_address_invoice":"4","id_cart":"1","id_currency":"1","id_lang":"1","id_customer":"1","id_carrier":"2","current_state":"5","module":"ps_checkpayment","invoice_number":"4","invoice_date":"2017-03-16 15:18:27","delivery_number":"4","delivery_date":"2017-03-16 15:18:27","valid":"1","date_add":"2017-03-16 14:36:24","date_upd":"2017-03-16 15:18:27","shipping_number":{"@attributes":{"notFilterable":"true"}},"id_shop_group":"1","id_shop":"1","secure_key":"b44a6d9efd7a0076a0fbce6b15eaf3b1","payment":"Payment by check","recyclable":"0","gift":"0","gift_message":{},"mobile_theme":"0","total_discounts":"0.000000","total_discounts_tax_incl":"0.000000","total_discounts_tax_excl":"0.000000","total_paid":"55.000000","total_paid_tax_incl":"55.000000","total_paid_tax_excl":"55.000000","total_paid_real":"55.000000","total_products":"53.000000","total_products_wt":"53.000000","total_shipping":"2.000000","total_shipping_tax_incl":"2.000000","total_shipping_tax_excl":"2.000000","carrier_tax_rate":"0.000","total_wrapping":"0.000000","total_wrapping_tax_incl":"0.000000","total_wrapping_tax_excl":"0.000000","round_mode":"0","round_type":"0","conversion_rate":"1.000000","reference":"XKBKNABJK","associations":{"order_rows":{"@attributes":{"nodeType":"order_row","virtualEntity":"true"},"order_row":[{"id":"1","product_id":"2","product_attribute_id":"10","product_quantity":"1","product_name":"Blouse - Color : White, Size : M","product_reference":"demo_2","product_ean13":{},"product_isbn":{},"product_upc":{},"product_price":"26.999852","unit_price_tax_incl":"27.000000","unit_price_tax_excl":"27.000000"},{"id":"2","product_id":"3","product_attribute_id":"13","product_quantity":"1","product_name":"Printed Dress - Color : Orange, Size : S","product_reference":"demo_3","product_ean13":{},"product_isbn":{},"product_upc":{},"product_price":"25.999852","unit_price_tax_incl":"26.000000","unit_price_tax_excl":"26.000000"}]}}},{"id":"2","id_address_delivery":"4","id_address_invoice":"4","id_cart":"2","id_currency":"1","id_lang":"1","id_customer":"1","id_carrier":"2","current_state":"5","module":"ps_checkpayment","invoice_number":"3","invoice_date":"2017-03-16 15:18:27","delivery_number":"3","delivery_date":"2017-03-16 15:18:27","valid":"1","date_add":"2017-03-16 14:36:24","date_upd":"2017-03-16 15:18:27","shipping_number":{"@attributes":{"notFilterable":"true"}},"id_shop_group":"1","id_shop":"1","secure_key":"b44a6d9efd7a0076a0fbce6b15eaf3b1","payment":"Payment by check","recyclable":"0","gift":"0","gift_message":{},"mobile_theme":"0","total_discounts":"0.000000","total_discounts_tax_incl":"0.000000","total_discounts_tax_excl":"0.000000","total_paid":"75.900000","total_paid_tax_incl":"75.900000","total_paid_tax_excl":"75.900000","total_paid_real":"75.900000","total_products":"73.900000","total_products_wt":"73.900000","total_shipping":"2.000000","total_shipping_tax_incl":"2.000000","total_shipping_tax_excl":"2.000000","carrier_tax_rate":"0.000","total_wrapping":"0.000000","total_wrapping_tax_incl":"0.000000","total_wrapping_tax_excl":"0.000000","round_mode":"0","round_type":"0","conversion_rate":"1.000000","reference":"OHSATSERP","associations":{"order_rows":{"@attributes":{"nodeType":"order_row","virtualEntity":"true"},"order_row":[{"id":"3","product_id":"2","product_attribute_id":"10","product_quantity":"1","product_name":"Blouse - Color : White, Size : M","product_reference":"demo_2","product_ean13":{},"product_isbn":{},"product_upc":{},"product_price":"26.999852","unit_price_tax_incl":"27.000000","unit_price_tax_excl":"27.000000"}
```

To make it easier I've also created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvmkdhxr/)

So my question is, since the first set of the filter is working (3). Why isn't my on click function working? with the `console.log()` I checked if the id is selected and it is. So why isn't the filter updated?

If you have any questions please ask them as comments.

As always, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have used `ng-controller="OrderController"` 2 times in your code, they actually are 2 different instance of the controller so their variables such as `$scope.currentOrder` do not share with each other.

Comment: @Icycool both blocks of code are actually `ng-includes` and seperate from each other. Thats why i'm using `ng-controller` twice. See it as, one view file, two `ng-includes` one is the summary list, the other is the "more information block"

Comment: The issue still stand though - different uses of same controller class create different instances, and their variables are not shared. You need to create a service to share data among them.

Comment: @Icycool alright, so could you give a small example of how i would be able to create that service?

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31108629/5039495

Comment: @lcycool Wow! your explanation worked, since the controller was called two times the connection between both views didn't work. Instead of using the data service for sharing i just edited the view file and called the controller from that point. It works correctly now!

Comment: @Deathstorm, since this question is duplicate please close bounty, and mark it as such.

Comment: @przemo_li Fun fact: I set the bounty on the wrong question, this one is already solved. (:

Comment: @przemo_li Why is it a duplicate question?

Comment: Becuase of @lcycool comment. Root cuase is having multiple instances of controller, where you need shared data. Or is there still something to be solved in your question?

Comment: @pzermo_li, i still need to write the data share but besides that. No there is no further questions that need to be solved. I will close the question a.s.a.p.